# Sumproduct formula returns a #VALUE! error when the last array refers to a column with formulas in every row. MS Excel 2010

Tags: arrays, error-handling, excel-formula, excel-2010, array-formulas

I am trying to find an easy way to calculate commissions off of sales on multiple sheets within a workbook.  Each month, I need to find the total net profit for only items sold within the specified month.

The formula I am currently using is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT('Sheet Name'!$P$3:P24,"MY")=TEXT($G$4,"MY"))*'Sheet Name'!$M$3:M24)
```

- Column P shows the Sold Date,
- Column M includes a formula in each row to calculate the net profit, and
- cell G4 is where I would enter the month & year I am currently working with.

I have come to the conclusion that it only gives me the #VALUE! error because of the formula *in each row* of Column M (example: `=IF(OR(F15=0,G15=0)," ",(F15-L15))` ).

When I reference a different column (in place of Column M) that does not contain formulas it works perfectly (example: `=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT('Sheet Name'!$P$3:P24,"MY")=TEXT($G$4,"MY"))*'Sheet Name'!$G$3:G24)` ). Also, changing the astrisk to a comma causes the formula to calculate incorrectly and add the `(--(TEXT` double negative does not fix the problem.

How to I get this array to calculate without removing the formulas from Column M?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume it is giving you a #VALUE error because your formula results in text (a space) and it errors when trying to multiply a space by a number (aka True or False). I think you would be better served changing your M column formula to `=IF(OR(F15=0,G15=0),0,(F15-L15))`. Do you have a specific reason to not make it evaluate to `0`? Also is there a reason you are converting to text to do your month/year check?

Try something like this: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH('Sheet Name'!$P$3:P24)=MONTH($G$4)),--(YEAR('Sheet Name'!$P$3:P24)=YEAR($G$4)),'Sheet Name'!$M$3:M24)`. Of course this is dependent on entering the dates as actual dates. The `--` is used to change a logical/boolean (true/false) into a 1 or 0. It won't do anything useful to text. For example, it should also work as `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH('Sheet Name'!$P$3:P24)=MONTH($G$4))*(YEAR('Sheet Name'!$P$3:P24)=YEAR($G$4))*'Sheet Name'!$M$3:M24)` since the multiplication converts the truthy statements to numbers. The trick is to make sure when everything else evaluates, you have `=sumproduct(numbers,numbers,numbers)`. Your instance is one array of `=sumproduct(numbers/text)`.

Comment: I do actually want the cells in Column M to show a blank until the Sold Price (Column F) and the Cost of Merchandise (Column G) have values.  I do appreciate the suggestion, though.   

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH('Sheet Name'!$P$3:P24)=MONTH($G$4)),--(YEAR('Sheet Name'!$P$3:P24)=YEAR($G$4)),'Sheet Name'!$M$3:M24)` is the formula that worked for me and is calculating correctly.  I did have a hunch that the formula resulting in text was the problem, but I wasn't 100% and I didn't know a better way to write it before receiving your advice.  

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: So you just need to resolve the issue with blank costs in column M then? I believe `=IF(OR(F15=0,G15=0),"",(F15-L15))` will work, but I have not tested it.

Comment: Yes, Column M is fine.  Thank you so much for your help!!  (Sorry I didn't accept sooner... I'm new here.)